# How to update an instance variable when another variable is changed?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following class and I want the instance variable api_id_bytes to update.

```
class ExampleClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.api_key = ""
        self.api_id = ""
        self.api_id_bytes = self.api_key.encode('utf-8')
```

I'd like to be able to have this outcome:

```
>>>conn = ExampleClass()
>>>conn.api_key = "123"
>>>conn.api_id = "abc"

>>>print(conn.api_id_bytes)
b'123'
>>>
```

I basically need the self.api_key.encode('utf-8') to run when an api_id is entered but it doesn't, it only does through the initial conn = ExampleClass().

I'm not sure what this is called so searching didn't find an answer.

Comment: A 'setter' could be used. Or, expose a method `def use_api_auth(self, id, key)`, which would be my preference here as it also accounts for both id and key at the same time..

Comment: For a 'setter' (and also 'getter'), https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/property/setter.html , https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html, https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Comment: Or you could make `api_id_bytes` a property that calculates the correct value on demand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you could do it by making `api_id_bytes` a [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property).

```
class ExampleClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.api_key = ""
        self.api_id = ""
    @property
    def api_id_bytes(self):
        return self.api_key.encode('utf-8')
```

Now `conn.api_id_bytes` will always be correct for the current value of `conn.api_key`.

Comment: Legend, thank you for taking the time to post that.  I read the docs others had suggest but this worked perfectly!